# fortran and c reading "here document"

Tags: gcc, fortran, sh, heredoc

I am porting a large set of f77 programs to a new system, compiling with
gfortran rather than g77. Some of these programs use both a Fortran read
statement, and a (custom) C routine to read from standard input. This
works fine if the programs are run interactively, but not if the
interactive input is provided as a separate file that is piped to the
program, or as a here document. For these last two cases, if a Fortran
read is followed by a C getchar, the getchar returns EOF rather than the
unread part of the file.

Replacing the Fortran read with a call to fget solves the problem for
piped input, but not for a here document.

All this using the sh shell, on Mac OS X 10.8.4; gfortran is gcc 4.6.2
and gcc for C is the Apple build, 4.2.1 (I do intend to retry this with
consistant gcc but can't at the moment).

Anyone know a reason, or a solution?

Here is a script that creates and compiles two programs, and demonstrates
the problem:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat << XXX > tmp.f
character*1 sym,dum
call fget(sym)
write(6,*) sym
call tmpc
stop
end
XXX
cat << XXX > tmpc.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
float tmpc_()
{
int c;
      c=getchar();
      fprintf(stderr,"1. c is %o %d\n",c,c);
      c=getchar();
      fprintf(stderr,"2. c is %o %d\n",c,c);
      c=getchar();
      fprintf(stderr,"3. c is %o %d\n",c,c);
      fprintf(stderr,"\n");
return(0);   
}
XXX
gcc -c tmpc.c
gfortran tmp.f tmpc.o
cat << XXX > tmp
*
2.34 12
XXX
cat tmp | a.out
a.out << XXX
*
2.34 12
XXX
rm tmp.f a.out tmpc.c tmpc.o tmp
```

The output is (the first four lines when the file is piped, the second
set when it is a here document):

```
 *
1. c is 12 10
2. c is 62 50
3. c is 56 46


 *
1. c is 37777777777 -1
2. c is 37777777777 -1
3. c is 37777777777 -1
```

The first set is correct: the values of c correspond to the characters
        \n 2 .
as they should.

Comment: What happens when you try a.out < XXX?  In my very limited use of shell scripts, I've never come across using << as input.  It is normally just <.

Comment: it could be a CR vs LF issue.  In any case is the "here document" syntax worth losing sleep over?  Just use the tmp file form if it works.

Comment: @cup the << XXX syntax says to pipe lines from the shell script up to the matching XXX. Basically an inline external file. (ive used it many times without knowing its called a "here document"..)

Comment: OK, got it: when you input from the script, it fails and when you input from a pipe simulating console input, it works.  It is probably something to do with buffered and unbuffered input since you are using two separate input systems.  On some C compilers, mixing getc with scanf also gives similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC the g77 runtime I/O library was implemented on top of C stdio, whereas the GFortran I/O library uses the POSIX I/O apis directly and does its own buffering. It's thus likely that the C and Fortran buffers get out of sync and problems ensue.

Also, in some GFortran versions there have been bugs in handling of non-seekable files.

In general, avoid doing mixed language I/O to the same file. It's perfectly Ok to use C for one file and Fortran for another, though. Just don't mix them.